# Queuing operations inbound from API

Tags: java, dropwizard

I written a web service (DropWizard) that takes accepts requests via `POST` to perform operations that may take considerable time. Considerable time meaning that it could take anywhere from 1-5 minutes to complete.

That said the caller doesn't need a response. Just a simple `200` to acknowledge receipt of the message is enough. It's actually a PayPal IPN WebHook for anybody who is curious.

I only want to perform one of these operations at a time (with the option to increase in future) so that my system doesn't overload.

What kind of queue mechanism should I consider using. This probably goes without say but I must assume that the API instance can be killed at any time, thus clearing memory. I will need a temporary place to store the queue so I can resume where the server left off when restarted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache Kafka Queue. The documentation is pretty clear. It should help you out.

http://kafka.apache.org/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use, activeMQ with persistance. Its very light weight and easy to use. Have a look at http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html it will guide you through the step by step process.